# Selenium/python - Clicking all elements which are in a particular div

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am learning to scrape using selenium and was trying one of the SAP pages.

The link is : 
https://help.sap.com/viewer/2e167338c1b24da9b2a94e68efd79c42/4.2.4/en-US/

What I intend to do is get all the leaf/last level urls for this page present on the table of contents panel. Unfortunately, the links are not in html and only if we click on each side button on the left panel, will it expand, also, each button click can have more nested buttons! I need to click all these and get the underlying data.

I starting by identifying the xpath and tried clicking them, but it gives the following error :

```
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/tarun/Downloads/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://help.sap.com/viewer/2e167338c1b24da9b2a94e68efd79c42/4.2.4/en-US/")
time.sleep(20) #tried this
htmlSource = driver.page_source

buttonsSidePanel = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="toc"]/treecontrol/div/div[*]/div[1]/div[1]')
#also tried - //*[@id="toc"]/treecontrol/div/div[*]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]
for x in buttonsSidePanel:
    x.click()
    time.sleep(1)


driver.close()
```

The error : `ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible`

I have a few questions in this regard (apologies if some of them are naive)
 1. )The elements are visible in the html when I do inspect element! Am unable to figure out what is it that am doing wrong?

2. Also, how do I recursively click the underlying buttons if a button click shows more buttons, or is there a way by which I can click all buttons at once and then scrape the data? I looked at a few stackoverflow questions, but couldn't resolve my task

3.)After clicking the button, now how do we scrape the newly generated content?

Comment: at what line are you getting the exception?

Comment: @PrakashPalnati - in the x.click() line, as one of the answers suggested, it might be a problem with timing, because once out of 7 times, it worked, but i am still not sure and not also sure about where to add time.sleep()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running simple js script using selenium's execute_script.
Try this.You can alsi identify using class name.

```
jscode='''
var allButtons=document.getElementsByClassName('collapseicon');
for( b of allButtons){
   b.click();
 }
'''

driver.execute_script(jscode);
```

Also to scrape including the child drop downs, you are getting all the page content/response in the call below use, request module to check this,

```
import requests
url = "https://help.sap.com/http.svc/getpagecontent?deliverableInfo=1&deliverable_loio=2e167338c1b24da9b2a94e68efd79c42&language=en-US&state=PRODUCTION&toc=1&version=4.2.4"
r = requests.get(url)
print (r.json())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will try this, also, can you guide me on the 3rd question?

Comment: what do u mean by scraping the new content?the child drop downs?? they will be having their own selectors. And if you are scraping I would suggest using urllib/requests for this website as they API calls going and response is having everything that is being dispayed. You can just save the response in this case.

Comment: yes, i mean the child drop downs, but how will we know what the new selectors are? as in a script? could you please elaborate on the urllib/requests part? will the response have everything that's displayed that means even the internal links, is it?? I don't think the javascript part would be rendered!

Comment: also, instead of classname, is there something where i can use xpath?

Comment: https://help.sap.com/http.svc/getpagecontent?deliverableInfo=1&deliverable_loio=2e167338c1b24da9b2a94e68efd79c42&language=en-US&state=PRODUCTION&toc=1&version=4.2.4

look at this call in the network tab of your browser and observe the JSON resposne. It has got everything that is in the left side drop downs. Use requests or urllib for getting the response. I will add code for this in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That helped a lot! can i bother you with the Last bit of the question - can we automatically know which are such urls from which the response is received. I mean i was trying to extract such information for a lot of pages? Again, thanks a ton!

Comment: generally there is no automatic way especially when you are scraping external websites(for internal, you might get to know from dev team). Usually we check the network tab for XHR requests in the browser with meaningful names and check their responses. (in our case the url says getpagecontent)

Answer (score 1):

This just might be because the requested element is not visible immediately and the connection moves on.

Try using an expected condition wait (EC wait).

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="toc"]/treecontrol/div/div[*]/div[1]/div[1]')))
```

This would wait until an element is visible and then executes the further steps.

Comment: Did you mean

htmlSource = driver.page_source


button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="toc"]/treecontrol/div/div[*]/div[1]/div[1]')))


button.click()

Comment: This still gives the same error, were you able to replicate the result?